# .htaccess redirect from old site to new site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect old links to a new site via htaccess. I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.co.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /2013/08/ http://www.mysite.co.uk/whats-on/news/
```

is the attached correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` rules and keep specific redirects before generic ones.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^2013/08/ http://www.mysite.co.uk/whats-on/news/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```